# Scala - not using null in a case statement guard

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a function

```
def withEnrichment[T](f: (AccountEnrichment) => Option[T] Or ErrorMessage) = 
        (Option(xa.getEnrichment) match {
    case None => Good(None)   
    case Some(e: AccountEnrichment) => f(e)
    case _ => Bad("not an AccountEnrichment")}) 
badMap {"enrichment: " + _}
```

I need to add a guard to it so it ignores accounts of a certain type.

```
case Some(g: AccountEnrichment) 
    if (g.getAccount != null && g.getAccount.getId == "BADACCOUNT") 
        => Bad("account: id cannot be BADACCOUNT")
```

This works, however I'd like to do it without using the null keyword. The g.getAccount is from a Java library and can and will be null.

Comment: any reason why you want to avoid null check comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Option is applied on null it returns None.

```
scala> Option(null)
res0: Option[Null] = None
```

this property of `Option` can be used instead of null comparison in your code.

```
case Some(g: AccountEnrichment) 
    if (Option(g.getAccount).isEmpty && g.getAccount.getId == "BADACCOUNT") 
        => Bad("account: id cannot be BADACCOUNT")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need an extra `case` with a guard if you already have `case Some(e: AccountEnrichment) => f(e)`. You can modify it to:

```
case Some(e: AccountEnrichment) => Option(e.getAccount)
    .filterNot(_.getId == "BADACCOUNT")
    .map(_ => f(e))
    .getOrElse(Bad("account: id cannot be BADACCOUNT"))
```